# How do I stop a WPF DataGrid TextColumn cell from growing taller due to newlines?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

**Background:**

I have a DataGrid with multiple TextColumns. One column is read-only, and bound to the text of a TextBox that's outside of the DataGrid. This TextBox is a multi-line textbox, meaning that AcceptsReturn = true and TextWrapping = Wrap.

**Problem:**

When a user enters multiple lines in the multi-line TextBox, the bound DataGridCell (and its row) vertically grow so all the text appears.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to get a vertical scrollbar to appear within the cell, when multiple lines should appear?
2. Generally, what are other techniques to circumvent the growth of a DataGridCell, and its row, due to multi-line content?

**Research:**

I know I can prevent a DataGridRow's growth by forcibly setting its Height. However, that doesn't trigger a scrollbar.

And I confirmed that WordWrap is off for the TextBlock within the DataGridCell.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up being a bit flexible with my requirements and came up with this style:

```
<Style
    TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCellsPresenter}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCellsPresenter}}"
    >
    <Setter
        Property="MaxHeight"
        Value="25"
        />
</Style>
```

By setting MaxHeight on my DataGridCellsPresenters, I can trigger vertical scrollbars without directly interfering with row heights. And I can apply it consistently across my application, rather than per column.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and a `ScrollViewer` inside it? For example:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyText">
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="30" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding YourText}" />
   </ScrollViewer>
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```